# Manage label text dynamically not work properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

```
CGFloat constrainedSize = 500.0f;

UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:19]; //or any other font that matches what you will use in the UILabel
CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: myFont
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedSize, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

lblDescription=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,y, 300,textSize.height)];
```

i have tried this code for manage the dynamic text. but if the data comes larger it will not display the whole text.

Comment: Have you looked at `UITextView` ?

Comment: Why you hard code 300?? Why not to place dynamic width their? Just right textSize.width instead of 300 and see what will be output.

Answer (score 1):

You constrain the size to width = 500pt, but your textfield is only 300pt wide.

Edit:

It seems, I wasn't clear. If you calculate the height of the label with sizeWithFont and give as constraint a width of 500pt (constrainedSize) and use the calculated height then on a label with only 300pt width, the calculated height is not correct.

This is how it works for me:

```
CGFloat constrainedSize = 300.0f;

UIFont * myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:19]; //or any other font that matches what you will use in the UILabel
CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont: myFont
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(constrainedSize, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UILabel* lblDescription=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, constrainedSize, textSize.height)];
lblDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lblDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
lblDescription.font = myFont;
lblDescription.text = myText;
```

Again: use the same attributes for the label (font, size, lineBreakMode) as you use for the calculation, otherwise it won't fit.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are alloc and initing the `UILabel`, and never reset it's frame for bigger size text.

Simply set the frame of the UILabel after a text size change.

This line sets the size of the label, to textSize.height and it doesn't change.

```
        lblDescription=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,y, 300,textSize.height)];
```

You can call setFrame to programmatically change this.

Answer (score 0):

To display a larger text/Multiline text you should use `UITextView` instead. It is designed to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

hi here is code to set dynamic text in label

```
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,9999);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                                      constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                          lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    label.frame = newFrame;
```

i hope this is helping to you..